# Como alterar o local do preview do Bootstrap File Input?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-3, plugin

Eu preciso mudar o local onde aparece o preview das imagens, colocar ele dentro de outra div pois ele está sendo colocado automaticamente acima do input file. Até agora não encontrei nada na documentação que mostrasse como alterar isso.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu quero fazer é que o preview seja sempre colocado dentro de uma div com o id preview por exemplo e não somente ser criado uma div automaticamente, mas tenho dificuldades com javascript.

Comment: Qual plugin você está usando? Não tem documentação dele pra verificar se existe algum parâmetro que você possa trocar a posição ou o local?

Comment: O nome dele é: Bootstrap File Input

Comment: Você pode utilizar um template. Creio eu que nesse exemplo [link]http://plugins.krajee.com/file-advanced-usage-demo#advanced-example-6
vc tem a config `code {browse}\n" +
            "       {upload}\n" +
            "       {remove}\n `

Comment: Link do site: http://plugins.krajee.com/file-basic-usage-demo

Comment: pelo que percebi ele cria na imagem uma div com a class file-preview, uma sugestão minha, caso não encontre nada é sempre no evento de selecionar a imagem você manipular essa div. apenas uma idéia

Comment: vlw vou ver no script então oq eu faço

Comment: Infelizmente ainda não consegui mudar o local onde ele cria a div do preview